# Create more than 8000 pdf based on line item

Tags: salesforce, integration

We have a web service callout and we are getting a response when I get a response I need to create the PDF based on the record's line item number field.

1. one opportunity has 1 line item and the line item has a field called number.

So while creating line item if I update number as 1000 then on the button click I have to create 1000 pdf file and attach to the opportunity.
I am thinking to implement the Batch apex or is there any other option like Queuable Apex.

I have created a batch class that updating the record with the pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Batch apex would need some fixed amount of records to run on. Typically it's done as a query locator, you could also use the [`implements Iterable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm) version. So if you have all these Opportunities in SF - cool; otherwise it might look cleaner if you implement iterable and for example your `hasNext` & `next` will be doing the callouts.

Queueables and Schedulables could work too if you need a "daisy chain" of jobs. You'll have to make sure next one gets triggered even if current one encountered an error I guess. In that sense batch apex might be cleaner (next execute will be triggered even if previous execute fails). Plus you get nice wrap-up finish() method, while Queueable-based implementation might have to fake it somehow.

And last but not least - batch apex could run multiple executes at same time (they are independent, right?), as long as you don't add `Database.Stateful` to the mix. Queueables will always run one at a time.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm says

> No limit is enforced on the depth of chained jobs, which means that
> you can chain one job to another job and repeat this process with each
> new child job to link it to a new child job. (...)
>
> When chaining jobs, you can add only one job from an executing job
> with System.enqueueJob, which means that only one child job can exist
> for each parent queueable job. Starting multiple child jobs from the
> same queueable job isn’t supported.

Last thing - are you sure you won't hit limits. I'm not talking about "max 100 callouts" or "total timeouts in callouts max 2 minutes", I'm talking about the 24h ones. Like "The maximum number of asynchronous Apex method executions" = 250K unless you have lots of licenses. If you'd be calling TO salesforce you'd also have to look at API limits (~ 1K * count of users in prod, in sandbox flat 5 millions), FROM salesforce it's less of an issue

Comment: I implemented the batch to update the record after I get the response, so there will not be any callout limits. Just the case is after I get the response from callout it will store in wrapper class than I am using this wrapper to update the records in salesforce. It's like one callout and gets the response then updates the record values based on the response.

Comment: Sounds like you have right solution then. If you have records in SF it's natural to iterate over them in batch, queueables/schedulables/@future/continuation feels more suitable for "ok, here's next small chunk of work. and another. and another. is it done yet? no, ok, one more". Possibly with user waiting for some long operation to complete.

Comment: So I think batch would be the best as queuable will roll back everything is one record fails, also I can iterate a list in batch and execute it and create pdf.